# Conversion of saved SVC model with RBF Kernel to Tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

Is there a way to convert support vector classifier with rbf kernel to tf model?

I am aware of converting support vector classifier with linear kernel because there exists `coef_` where we can find parameters and assign to tf model. Got this idea from [how to convert saved model from sklearn into tensorflow/lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723922/how-to-convert-saved-model-from-sklearn-into-tensorflow-lite/66330086#66330086).

However `_coef` wont be there for rbf , so i am not sure on how to convert this model to an tf model.