# Is there any way to use sklearn complex model in android

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I searched alot but not found how to use model of sklearn in android .Yes simple model like find possibilities we can convert it into json and then can use via api in android but when we deal with live videos then what??

And also my second doubt is " can we use sklearn and tenserflow both in one model? "

And also in android is there only way to make ML model via tenserflow lite?

In kaggle i found major codes written in sklearn and also YouTube has lot of tutorial in sklearn for ML.And majority of videos are on how to deploy on web only .

I am fully beginner in ML .And i do research before learning anything .

So please could you give me suggestions on How can i start doing ML for android only not for web(Roadmap like thing).

Is tenserflow the only way to do ML in android?

Thank you .

Comment: Question needs some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi! You can assign weights from Sklearn model to TF model then convert it to TfLite model as this thread suggests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330086/11530462